# How to upload iOS app made in Xcode 6

Tags: xcode5, swift, app-store-connect, xcode6

I have build an app using Swift in Xcode 6, and I would like to upload it. I already read that it is not possible to upload an application using a beta version of Xcode, So I decided to try uploading it using Xcode 5.

I have followed all the neccecary steps from the normal process of uploading an app, but Xcode keeps on giving me this error:

```
The Bundle is not signed using an Apple submission certificate
```

I have been trying things four hours. regenerating certificates, App-id's, etcetera. I even restarted Xcode and rebooted my mac.

Can anybody confirm whether and how I can upload my app?

Comment: In this case, the problem that you're running into has nothing to do with swift.  It has to do with, as the error message says, your application isn't properly signed.  That said, the definitive answers below are absolutely correct.  You won't be able to submit applications compiled in Xcode 6 (regardless of language) until shortly before iOS 8 and/or Yosemite are released some time this fall.

Comment: In every WWDC there is a beta Xcode which we can not use it to submit our apps until they release it to the public. It usually supports developing and app for newer iOS version that nobody has it out there! So you have to wait until these are accessible by public too. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot upload an app made with Swift yet. Xcode 5 will fail at some point on uploading since Apple has said it's not supported. Unfortunately impossible for now.

See this: https://developer.apple.com/swift/

> You can begin using Swift code immediately to implement new features in
>   your app, or enhance existing ones. New Swift code co-exists along
>   side your existing Objective-C files in the same project, making it
>   easy to adopt. And when iOS 8 and OS X Yosemite are released this
>   fall, you can submit apps that use Swift to the App Store and Mac App
>   Store.

Answer (score 4):

You can't upload an app written in Swift yet.

Quoting [Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/swift/).

> And when iOS 8 and OS X Yosemite are released this fall, you can submit apps that use Swift to the App Store and Mac App Store.

Answer (score 0):

As of [September 9, 2014, you can submit apps to the app store built with Swift and XCode 6](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=09082014b). This predated the general release of XCode 6, so you should have used the latest GM seed of Xcode 6 until the general release of Xcode 6 was made available through the App Store on September 18, 2014.